# My image does not show at all

Tags: php, jquery

I am pulling my image from the database to display it on my page however it wont show. to confirm that the image is being called from the database i output the image name on the title= when you place the mouse on the unseen image you can see the image name but the image itself does not show at all. the website is this: 
http://clicktravelnstay.com/desti_list.php?details=19

```
  <div id="imgdisplay">
                     <div class="pagecontainer">
                         <div class="galleryCredit">Hotel Photos</div>
                         <div class="galleryType">Preview</div>
                         <div class="clear_both"></div>
                         <div class="galleryContent">
                                 <!--image goes herewidth:650px; height:300px;-->
                                 <!--This is Where the wide image and the caption icon will be placed-->
                                    <div class="galleryThumbnail">
                                    <?php
                                        $query = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE hotel_id = {$hotel['hotel_id']}";
                                                  $image_set =  mysql_query($query,$connection);
                                                  while($image = mysql_fetch_array($image_set)){?>
                                                  <a href=\"img/photos/<?php $image['image_url'];?>" title="<?php echo $image['image_url']?>">
                                                  <img src="img/photos/<?php echo $image['image_url'];?>" width="75" height="75"/></a>           
                                                  <?php } ?> 
                                    <div class="clear_both"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="galleryPreview">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear_both"></div>
                                    <div class="clear_both"></div>
                                    <div class="gallery_preload_area"></div>
                            </div>



                     <!--image goes herewidth:650px; height:300px;-->


                     </div>
```

The following code is the Jquery code for the image gallery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".galleryThumbnail a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     //update thumbnail
     $(".galleryThumbnail a").removeClass("selected");
     $(".galleryThumbnail a").children().css("opacity","1");

     $(this).addClass("selected");
     $(this).children().css("opacity",".4");

     //setup thumbnails
     var photoCaption = $(this).attr('title');
     var photofullsize =$(this).attr('href');

         $(".galleryPreview").fadeOut(500, function(){ 

         $(".gallery_preload_area").html("")  
           // this is what is going to happen after the fadeout
           $(".galleryPreview").html("<a  href='"+ photofullsize +"' style=' background-image:url("+photofullsize+");'></a>");
           $(".galleryCaption").html("<p><a href='"+photofullsize+"' title='Click to view large'>View Large</a></p><p></p>")    
           $(".galleryPreview").fadeIn(500);

          });


});



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path

http://clicktravelnstay.com/img/photos/1344707033.png

returns a 404 (not found).

You're pulling the image name from the database successfully, but the actual image file does not exist on your server.

Comment: I just checked it is in the server

Comment: Just to confirm this. the same problem occurs in my local server.

Comment: It returns 404 - not found.  Double check the path.  Your first step is to get the link I posted returning the image.  You can then start to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: thanks you were right i changed the image name. Now the image is showing however the large image is not showing. i do not know how to work with jQuery any ideas from the above code please.

Comment: I'd start by fixing the code that Marc B suggested - i.e. remove the '\' after the href= and add the missing 'echo'.  It may be that the anchor href is used as the source for the large image.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the generated HTML:

```
<a href=\"img/photos/" title="1344707033.png">
        ^--- bad escape.
```

You're outputting invalid html, plus the href is just a path, not pointing at an actual image.

That means:

```
<a href=\"img/photos/<?php $image['image_url'];?>" title="<?php echo $image['image_url']?>">
                          ^---missing 'echo' 
    <img src="img/photos/<?php echo $image['image_url'];?>" width="75" height="75"/></a>
```

and `$image['image_url']` doesn't contain anything.

Comment: if it does not contain anything then how can it possibly show the name of the image when you place the mouse over it

Comment: if it is a bad escape then can you help to improve it please.